# Pytest tests fail because python superclass attributes are not found while testing subclasses with pytest

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance, pytest, fastapi, attributeerror

**Please I wish to stress this is not a duplicate, as I have read all the pytest subclasses questions here and none addresses the error I'm having.**

**My problem in a nutshell**: I pytest a subclass that fails because the test depends on superclass attributes to run, but pytest raises AttributeError on those attributes for the subclasses, while those attributes are well defined in superclass

I have two classes Entity a base class that handles id generation and error handling for common errors
Once a business rule validation error occurs entity adds that to the errors list and in it's init class it raises a ValueError if the errors list is not empty

**entity.py**

```
from abc import ABC
import uuid

# a util class containing basic validation bool functions. ex: is_valid_datetime
from util import Validator

class Entity(ABC):
    id: str
    errors: list[dict]

    def __init_(self) -> None:
        self.id = ""
        self.errors = []

        if not self.id:
            self.id = uuid.uuid4().hex

        self.validate()

    def validate(self) -> None:
        if len(self.errors) > 0:
           raise ValueError(self.errors)

    # simple example of a validation function
    def validate_is_datetime(self, attr_name: str, attr_value: datetime) -> bool:
        if Validator.is_valid_datetime(attr_value)
            return True
        else:
            self.errors.append(
                {
                    "type": "datetime",
                    "loc": f"Entity, {attr_name}",
                    "msg": "Attribute should be a valid datetime",
                    "input": attr_value
                }
            )
```

A Product class that inherits from entity.
**product.py**

```
from entity import Entity

class Product(Entity):
    name: str
    price: str

    def __init__(name: str, price: str) -> None:
        self.name = name
        # example of a validation that will fail during instantiation
        # I need it to fail to showcase the problem I'm having
        self.validate_is_datetime(name)

        self.price = price

        super().__init__()
```

testing my classes with *pytest*

Pytest fixtures
**conftest.py**

```
import pytest
from entity import Entity
from product import Product

@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def entity():
    return Entity()

@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def product():
    return Product(name="Iphone 8", price="150")
```

Test Product domain entity
**test_product.py**

```
# simple test to ensure correct instantiation
def test_name_is_iphone8(product: Product) -> None:
    assert product.name == "Iphone 8"
```

I start by running tests for Product model in test_product.py
`pytest`

Now obviously as defined earlier I expect the test to fail, because a ValueError will be raised during product instantiation, as I called in product init `self.validate_is_valid_datetime(self.name), name: str cannot be a valid datetime.

The result is the test fails, OK, but not raising a ValueError, but an AttributeError saying the **product object does not have an errors attribute**. So pytest does not get errors is defined in the superclass Entity and should be available in Product that inherits from it.

Comment: Okay, so first of, try to keep your questions succinct and include a minimal reproducible example (see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)).

Comment: Secondly, I don't think your problem has anything to do with `pytest`. I would guess your error might be that you're missing `self` as the first argument to `Product`'s `__init__` method.

Comment: Hey @M.O. thanks for answering! I finally found the problem, as you said it had nothing to do with pytest. I call the superclass init method too late in the product init method. The superclass (Entity class) init method should be called earlier (before any method that uses the errors attribute) as it inits the errors attribute. Python doesn't recognize class methods that are not initialized, so accessing an attribute that is not initialized raises a runtime AttributeError.

Comment: Thanks to @James Z too for helping with the typos

Answer (score 0):

sorry I found out the error I made (Been rushing this project a little too much):

In Product init method I call `super().__init__()` at the end of the Product.**init**() function.

```
   class Product(Entity):
       ...
       def __init__(name: str, price: str) -> None:
           self.name = name
           #the test that fails
           self.validate_is_datetime(self.name) #this function depends on errors attr that has yet to be initialized by the super class
           self.price = price
           super().__init__() # The errors attr is only initialized at this point so all functions using before this call will raise AttributeError
```

While it should be called much sooner because Entity init method initializes the errors attribute. In python if a class member is not initialized python doesn't recognize it when you call it. So the code for product.py init method should've been:

```
   class Product(Entity):
       ...
       def __init__(name: str, price: str) -> None:
           # call it first to initialize errors attr needed in validation methods
           super().__init__() 
           self.name = name
           #the test that fails
           self.validate_is_datetime(self.name)
           self.price = price
```

Now I doubt someone else makes the same stupid mistake, but if you get pytest attribute errors while testing your subclasses make sure your attributes are well initialized with values, defining it alone (ex: name: str) wouldn't make it.
If your attr is initialized in a superclass make sure it's init method is called at the appropriate time to initialize the needed attributes before they are used